# Any standards for :visited styling for CTA buttons?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, style, cta

I have used `:visited` in CSS for links for a long time and understand their value. However I have not thought of using it for buttons. My "CTA buttons" are usually soft CTAs that direct to valuable information. They are on cards near the second half of the page to engage the user one last time before they leave.

This is not used often for primary CTAs but helps people still looking for health information before committing to coming in for a visit.

The big question is have you ever used `:visited` on buttons?

I have not seen much research around its usage since the CTA tends to be a step you don't want them to return from but have them continue. These CTAs are there to maintain engagement and encouraging them to learn more by going to another and another until they have all the knowledge they need. Maybe these are not truly CTAs, so don't get caught up in that, but ultimately have you seen buttons with `:visited` styling and has the helped or hurt?

[image: Image of soft CTAs]

Comment: No. There are no standards.

Answer (score 2):

Consider completion/progress interfaces. One example are language learning applications such as Duolingo, where progress is displayed and the completion of the task is highlighted.

[image]

Another example is [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/front-end-web-development), where all the interface is laid out in a progression style. Mimicking the progress of the student across each lesson/stage.

[image]